# AWS Cloudfront Friendly url

Tags: amazon-web-services, url-rewriting, amazon-cloudfront

Using AWS cloudfront with S3 to host an angular-based web client.

Is there any rewrite rule or settings allowing one of the following examples? It is so unclear from what AWS are trying to exaplain.

1. Using friendly route, for example:

   domain.com?lang=en&fun=no => domain.com/en/no
2. Configuration folders to have a default file, for example:

   domain.com\en => domain.com (but now the client knows it has a parameter lang=en)

Obviously both of the example can be done with an html file which routes to the desired url BUT it doesn't work well with some sort of analytics models such as google's.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using 'AWS Lamda at the Edge' functionality to provide the custom rewriting you want:

> **Using CloudFront with Lambda@Edge**
>
> Lambda@Edge is an extension of AWS Lambda, a compute service that lets you execute functions that customize the content that CloudFront delivers. Lambda@Edge scales automatically, from a few requests per day
> to thousands per second. Processing requests at AWS locations closer
> to the viewer instead of on origin servers significantly reduces
> latency and improves the user experience.
>
> When you associate a CloudFront distribution with a Lambda@Edge
> function, CloudFront intercepts requests and responses at CloudFront
> edge locations. You can execute Lambda functions when the following
> CloudFront events occur:
>
> - When CloudFront receives a request from a viewer (viewer request)
> - Before CloudFront forwards a request to the origin (origin request)
> - When CloudFront receives a response from the origin (origin response)
> - Before CloudFront returns the response to the viewer (viewer response)

and here is an aCloudGuru blog post with lots of good examples, including one specifically about url rewriting:

https://read.acloud.guru/supercharging-a-static-site-with-lambda-edge-da5a1314238b

Answer (score 1):

In a multipage web app (say 12 pages), you will want to use an automated and worry-less strategy via **AWS Lamda@Edge**. It solves this completely.

First, create an AWS Lambda function and then attach your CloudFront as a trigger.

In the code section of this AWS Lamda page, add the snippet in the repository below.

https://github.com/CloudUnder/lambda-edge-nice-urls/blob/master/lambdaRewrite.js

Content delivery will still be as fast as you can blink your eyes.

**PS: Note the options in the readme section of the repo above**